# Which binary would be run when we have multiple installations?

Tags: bash, alias, executable, binary, which

I wanted to set gsettings as `/usr/bin/gsettings` so I created an alias. But I am not sure if that works:

```
$ type gsettings
gsettings is aliased to `/usr/bin/gsettings'
gsettings is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gsettings
gsettings is /usr/bin/gsettings

$ which gsettings
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gsettings
```

Also another example:

```
$ type pandoc
pandoc is aliased to `/usr/bin/pandoc'
pandoc is /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pandoc
pandoc is /usr/bin/pandoc
pandoc is /home/nikhil/.cabal/bin/pandoc

$ which pandoc
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pandoc
```

### Question

1. Can someone please clarify which binary for pandoc and gsettings would get executed when I type `pandoc` and `gsettings` on bash?
2. Does the order of output of `type` command has some significance?

### Note

```
$ type type
type is a function
type () 
{ 
    builtin type -a "$@"
}
type is a shell builtin
```

Comment: It seems like you have the answer to the first part with `which`, do you have reason to believe that it's not the one returned by `which`?

Comment: @user1794469 `which` is basically a worse `type`, you don't need it and `type` is always better. `which` will only check for executables in your `PATH`, it will ignore the alias, so it is not relevant here. In fact, it is wrong, since it suggests that `pandoc` would run `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pandoc`, when instead it would run `/usr/bin/pandoc` because aliases take precedence. See [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the order is important: whichever one is first in the output of `type` is the one that will be executed. So, in your case, `pandoc` would run the alias, `/usr/bin/pandoc`, and `gsettings` would run `/usr/bin/gsettings`.

I can't actually find where this behavior is documented, where it is stated that the first result of `type -a` is the one that will be executed, but you can see it in action if you unset and then reset an alias, for example:

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=tty'
ls is /sbin/ls
ls is /usr/bin/ls

$ unalias ls
$ type -a ls
ls is /sbin/ls
ls is /usr/bin/ls

$ alias ls='ls --color=tty'
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=tty'
ls is /sbin/ls
ls is /usr/bin/ls
```

As you can see, the alias goes back to the beginning when it is re-added. Compare to:

```
$ touch ~/bin/ls; chmod 755 ~/bin/ls
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=tty'
ls is /sbin/ls
ls is /home/terdon/bin/ls
ls is /usr/bin/ls
```

The new fake command I added, `~/bin/ls`, is shown after the alias (aliases always take precedence), after `/sbin/ls` and before `/usr/bin/ls`. This is precisely the order of execution as you can see by checking the order of the directories in my `$PATH`:

```
$ echo "$PATH"
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/terdon/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Note how `/home/terdon/bin` is after `/sbin` and before `/usr/bin`, and how this order is reflected in the output of `type`.

Finally, the simplest way to know which one will be executed is to run `type` without `-a`:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=tty'
```

That always returns just one item and that is the one that will be executed when you use that command.

Comment: Read the sequence of search in `man bash` under the **COMMAND EXECUTION** header (title in caps in the manual, I do not mean to yell here, if anyone thinks that I may, she/he would be mistaken).

Comment: @Isaac not sure what you mean. I read it, and it explains the sequence of command executions for the bash shell, yes. And we can perhaps assume that `type` will print its results according to the same sequence, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: The man bash say for type: *With no options, indicate how each name would be interpreted if used as a command name.*. And the interpretation of command names is the command execution listed before. So yes, the manual states how type should work.

Comment: This is because you said: *I can't actually find where this behavior is documented*. But AFAICT it actually is.